# SQL: Select the minimum of a subquery and grouping

Tags: mysql

I have some records of checkin and checkout of personnel in MySQL DB:

```
SELECT * FROM db
```

Results:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ID            Name       Lastname           in                out
1             James      Bond         20151014090000     20151014103000
2             James      Bond         20151014110000     20151014123000
3             James      Bond         20151014130000     20151014143000
4             James      Bond         20151014150000     20151014163000
5             James      Bond         20151014170000     20151014183000
6             James      Bond         20151014190000     20151014203000
7             Jason      Bourne       20151014090000     20151014103000
8             Jason      Bourne       20151014110000     20151014123000
9             Jason      Bourne       20151014130000     20151014143000
10            Jason      Bourne       20151014150000     20151014163000
11            Jason      Bourne       20151014170000     20151014183000
12            Jason      Bourne       20151014190000     20151014203000
13            Jack       Bauer        20151014090000     20151014103000
14            Jack       Bauer        20151014110000     20151014123000
15            Jack       Bauer        20151014130000     20151014143000
16            Jack       Bauer        20151014150000     20151014163000
17            Jack       Bauer        20151014170000     20151014183000
18            Max        Payne        20151014090000     20151014103000
19            Max        Payne        20151014110000     20151014123000
20            Max        Payne        20151014130000     20151014143000
21            Max        Payne        20151014150000     20151014163000
22            Max        Payne        20151014170000     20151014183000
```

I want to get the date closest to the current date below, ie entry, considering that are inside (IN).

I'm using, for a comparison with the current date in MySQL:

```
date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d%H%i%S')
```

Assuming that are 20151014133000

What I would like to get with a query is:

```
3             James      Bond         20151014130000     20151014143000
9             Jason      Bourne       20151014130000     20151014143000
15            Jack       Bauer        20151014130000     20151014143000
20            Max        Payne        20151014130000     20151014143000
```

Greetings and thank you very much in advance!

[EDIT1]
in and out are int's
I'm comparing it with actual time in that format because withthe operation:
date_actual - in_value = time_lapsed
For example:

20151014133000 - 20151014090000 = 43000

If I get the min value of time_lapsed, I'll get the date nearest to date_actual, and then I'll search on DB for that date grouping by names and lastnames.

Comment: use abs(now() - date) to get the closest date

Comment: What's the data type of your `in` and `out`?

Comment: It seems like a poor example. All the dates are equal to the target date. So 'nearness' is irrelevant.

Comment: you can select some of the last records(sort the in and out in descending order I am guessing in and out are of data type int or long int) as no entry would contain date past to now so the last records would be nearest ones

Comment: @Strawberry For comment that, better left.

Comment: group by name and last name and take max of IN date

Comment: is my answer the sort of thing you need? I'm using DISTINCT and max(in) which should give you the closest date to now() for each distinct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name`, `Lastname`, MAX(IN) FROM DB
```

Comment: I not use your answer at all, bit you give me the bit to follow ;) . Thanks!!

Comment: No problem! I'm sorry I'm always busy so I don't always have time to give elaborate answers.